# CMD opens instead of VBS

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I made a batch file:

```
echo set shell = createobject^("wscript.shell"^) : wscript.sleep^(1000^) : shell.sendkeys^("blablabla"^) : Shell.SendKeys "{Enter}" : wscript.sleep^(1000^) >"c:\folder\blabla.vbs"
start "c:\folder\blabla.vbs"
```

but when I open the batch file, it seems like CMD starts, but the VBS file doesn't. But when I open the VBS file manually, it works. So where is the problem. The VBS works manually, but the batch command doesn't starts the VBS. Please try it on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works without the start... ; )
if all you need is to run the vbs, then just use `"c:\folder\blabla.vbs"` instead of the start, or use `start "" "c:\folder\blabla.vbs"` if you need to use the start.

Comment: nephi12 what do you mean? It works without the start? Can you tell me something more, please?

Comment: I said that!... if all you need is to run the vbs, then just use "c:\folder\blabla.vbs", but if he wants to get control back at some point, start is a wise choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need START, look at its docs:

```
start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
         ===============

START ["title"] [/Dpath] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
      [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in  window title bar.
    path        Starting directory
    B           Start application without creating a new window. The
   ===                            =============================
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application
```

...

How the whole rigmarole interacts with Sendkeys remains to be seen.

Comment: Okay, so what would be the command to start the vbs? I'm sorry if I ask evident stuff, but I am very new to this. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

When using the start command and there are quotes on the command line the first set of quotes are the window title.

```
start "" "c:\folder\blabla.vbs"
```

What is the point of sleeping for one second as the last command?

Your script isn't robust. It's a good idea to use AppActivate before sendkeys to make sure it goes to right window. Using AppActivate will allow you to get rid of the first sleep command.

```
If WSHShell.AppActivate("Calculator")=False then 
    WshShell.Run "C:\windows\System32\calc.exe", 1, false 
End If
```

There's no need to do multiple sendkeys for most applications (web pages excepted).

Answer (score 0):

Using `start` to run a `vbs` file is the same as run this:

```
Wscript.exe "c:\folder\blabla.vbs"
```

People have the bad habit of try to use `Start` command to run all things when really is not needed, when running a file using `start` it just uses Windows `ShellExecute` logic to search the default associated program...both will work but you better try to run the right application like I've said instead of `start` command.